# How to do a sample rate conversion in Windows (and OSX)

Tags: c++, windows, macos, audio

I am about to write an audio file converter for my side job at the university.
As part of this I would need sample rate conversion. However, my professor said that it would be pretty hard to write a sample rate converter that was *both* of good quality *and* fast.

On my research on the subject, I found some functions in the OSX CoreAudio-framework, that could do a sample rate conversion (AudioConverter.h). After all, an OS has to have some facilities to do that for its own audio stack.

Do you know a similar method for C/C++ and Windows, that are either part of the OS or open source?
I am pretty sure that this function exists within DirectX Audio (XAudio2?), but I seem to be unable to find a reference to it in the MSDN library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try Secret Rabbit Code (= SRC = Sample Rate Conversion ) It's GPL, it's fast and it's high quality. http://www.mega-nerd.com/SRC/license.html

Comment: Do you have something BSD-licensed? Or at least LGPLed?

Comment: Too late to be useful - but for those arriving via Google the "opus-tools" package contains a resampler with very acceptable quality, BSD-licensed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about quality, check out http://src.infinitewave.ca/.  Very good comparisons on different resamplers.